# Salesforce Column naming conventions and queries

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to retrieve from Salesforce a column named "e2 Instance", however I cannot insert it with the space into the query.
Also I noticed that to query for "Account Type" I'd use such syntax:

```
SELECT Name, Id, Type from Account
```

How do I query for columns with spaces in the name? 
I tried inserting quotes - it did not work.
Or how do I get a list of available columns in the "code" format?

Comment: what is your question. Soql always return list of value.And You can use  space within '' as string i didn't get you at all

Comment: The question was about field naming conventions and list of fields.
Do you know how to select all? Like "*" in sql?

Comment: I guess you got answer for your question if not let me know :) happy clod development :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be confusing field label and field API name. It should be something like e2_Instance__c but to be sure got to Setup -> Customize -> Accounts -> Fields and see under Account Custom Fields & Relationships in API Name column.